# Merge two yml files

Tags: makefile, yaml, gnu-make

I am working on makefiles where I need to take two config files which are in yml format and merge them into single file.

Do we have any sight away command for doing so ?

Comment: This question isn't about make or makefiles.  First you should find commands that will do the merge, at your shell prompt.  Then you put those commands into your makefile.

Comment: You have to define what it means to "merge two yml config files into a single file".  It's trivial enough to "merge" them if by that you mean concatenate them: `cat file1.yml file2.yml > result.yml`.  But, most likely that's not good enough for what you want.

Comment: No, Thats not the case. i want to merge in a way that if the we have same keys in two yml files, then those content thould be merged and placed in single key. It should be correct i.e. syntactical wise yml file.

Comment: OK, well, then, your question is not a make question it's a yaml tooling question.  Once you figure out how to do that on the command line, it's trivial enough to put those same commands in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

[yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) probably does what you want.

v3 had

```sh
yq m file1.yaml file2.yaml > file3.yaml
```

In v4 this was [totally improved to be](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3#merging-documents)

```sh
yq eval-all 'select(fileIndex == 0) * select(filename == "file2.yaml")' file1.yaml file2.yaml > file3.yaml
```